# How to access file in jquery.filer for upload to Flask backend?

Tags: jquery, flask

Trying to use jquery.filer to upload images to my controller in Flask. I can't figure out how to access the file on the Flask side, however. Below is my jquery.filer init script where data = {} in the ajax POST.

Is there a way to send the file itself to my Flask backend? I'm familiar with request.file but nothing is being POST'd to my endpoint.

```
    $("#filer_input1").filer({
        limit: null,
        maxSize: null,
        extensions: null,
        changeInput: '<div class="jFiler-input-dragDrop"><div class="jFiler-input-inner"><div class="jFiler-input-icon"><i class="icon-jfi-cloud-up-o"></i></div><div class="jFiler-input-text"><h3>Drag & Drop files here</h3> <span style="display:inline-block; margin: 15px 0">or</span></div><a class="jFiler-input-choose-btn btn btn-custom waves-effect waves-light">Browse Files</a></div></div>',
        showThumbs: true,
        theme: "dragdropbox",
        templates: {
            box: '<ul class="jFiler-items-list jFiler-items-grid"></ul>',
            item: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                        <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                        <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo: 25}}</b></span>\
                                        <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-size2}}</span>\
                                    </div>\
                                    {{fi-image}}\
                                </div>\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                        <li>{{fi-progressBar}}</li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                        <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                    </ul>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </div>\
                    </li>',
            itemAppend: '<li class="jFiler-item">\
                            <div class="jFiler-item-container">\
                                <div class="jFiler-item-inner">\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-thumb">\
                                        <div class="jFiler-item-status"></div>\
                                        <div class="jFiler-item-info">\
                                            <span class="jFiler-item-title"><b title="{{fi-name}}">{{fi-name | limitTo: 25}}</b></span>\
                                            <span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-size2}}</span>\
                                        </div>\
                                        {{fi-image}}\
                                    </div>\
                                    <div class="jFiler-item-assets jFiler-row">\
                                        <ul class="list-inline pull-left">\
                                            <li><span class="jFiler-item-others">{{fi-icon}}</span></li>\
                                        </ul>\
                                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">\
                                            <li><a class="icon-jfi-trash jFiler-item-trash-action"></a></li>\
                                        </ul>\
                                    </div>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                        </li>',
            progressBar: '<div class="bar"></div>',
            itemAppendToEnd: false,
            removeConfirmation: true,
            _selectors: {
                list: '.jFiler-items-list',
                item: '.jFiler-item',
                progressBar: '.bar',
                remove: '.jFiler-item-trash-action'
            }
        },
        uploadFile: {
            url: "/api/files/register-persons",
            data: {},
            type: 'POST',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            beforeSend: function(itemEl, file){
                            console.log(itemEl, file)
                        },
            success: function(data, el){
                var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
                el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-success\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-check-circle\"></i> Success</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            },
            error: function(el){
                var parent = el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").parent();
                el.find(".jFiler-jProgressBar").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                    $("<div class=\"jFiler-item-others text-error\"><i class=\"icon-jfi-minus-circle\"></i> Error</div>").hide().appendTo(parent).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            }
        },
        captions: {
            button: "Choose Files",
            feedback: "Choose files To Upload",
            feedback2: "files were chosen",
            drop: "Drop file here to Upload",
            removeConfirmation: "Are you sure you want to remove this file?",
            errors: {
                filesLimit: "Only {{fi-limit}} files are allowed to be uploaded.",
                filesType: "Only Images are allowed to be uploaded.",
                filesSize: "{{fi-name}} is too large! Please upload file up to {{fi-maxSize}} MB.",
                filesSizeAll: "Files you've choosed are too large! Please upload files up to {{fi-maxSize}} MB."
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is my Flask script:

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify

@mod.route('/api/files/register-persons', methods=['POST'])
def registerPersons():
    file = request.files['file']
    return file
```

Comment: And what's the value of the `name` attribute on the element with `id="filer_input1"`?

Comment: <input type="file" name="files" id="filer_input1" multiple="multiple">

Comment: So you need to use `request.files['files']`, because that's the name of the field.

Comment: That doesn't return anything though. It has something to do with the jquery.filer library. I'm not sure how to POST the file itself.

Comment: What does the network tab of your browser's developer tools tell you is being sent to the server?